# Simple Constraint Logic Programming sample CLP(Q) gives error in Prolog

Tags: prolog, clpq

I've started to learn Prolog and I follow the RIPTutorial PDF. At the [Constraint Logic Programming CLP(Q)](https://riptutorial.com/prolog/example/7482/clp-q-) section, it says:

Constraint Logic Programming CLP(Q) implements reasoning over *rational* numbers

Example:

```
?- { 5/6 = X/2 + 1/3 }.
X = 1.
```

When I've tried this line on SWI-Prolog on Windows, it gave:

`ERROR: Unknown procedure: {}/1 (DWIM could not correct goal)`

The same line on commandline SWI-Prolog-7.2.0 on macOS gives:

`ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: {}/1 (DWIM could not correct goal)`

How to get the expected output of `X = 1.` ?

Comment: Did you load the library first?

Comment: @jkiiski No, I didn't. In the tutorial, there was no mention of any library.

Comment: @Guy Coder, when I entered `use_module(library(clpr)).` it worked out okay.  In the tutorial there was no mention of `use_module`

Comment: By all means, do use `library(clpq)` and **not** `clpr`.

Comment: @GuyCoder: The question applies to many Prologs alike. In fact, SICStus was first in the early 1990s to feature that very `clpq` library. Reserve the swi-prolog tag to questions that are specific to SWI alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [SWI-Prolog](https://www.swi-prolog.org/).

As noted in the comments you need to load the code for [CLP(Q)](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpqr) first.

```
?- use_module(library(clpq)).
true
```

Then enter the query as in the example.

```
?- {5/6 = X/2 + 1/3}.
X = 1.
```